# Как можно бороться с конфликтом методов расширения?

Tags: c#, linq

Вот есть библиотека `MoreLINQ` и с выходом новых фреймворков там появился собственный метод Append и => возникло пересечение.

Нагугли только решение в виде импорта статических методов:

```
using static MoreLinq.Extensions.LagExtension;
using static MoreLinq.Extensions.LeadExtension;
using MoreEnumerable = MoreLinq.MoreEnumerable;
```

Однако, в таком случае код становится громоздким, так как приходится использовать алиасы даже в тех местах, где пересечения нету.

Еще на ум пришла идея с созданием обертки на MoreLINQ, где удален пересекающийся метод, но решение выглядит слишком костыльно.

Есть ли какое-то элегантное решение?

Comment: Почему "костыльно"? Лично я не понимаю, почему из MoreLinq до сих пор не вырезали Append и Prepend, которые ныне представлены платформой, ибо раньше они так и поступали. Сделайте форк, вырежьте методы, соберите, закиньте в локальный NuGet репозиторий (если есть) и радуйтесь жизни

Comment: Вызывайте конфликтующие extension-методы как обычные статические, и все.